# ^ symbol with regex and PHP not working

Tags: php, regex

This simple regex expression:

```
~^(\d{6})~
```

Is not working on PHP preg_match. why?

```
 preg_match('~^(\d{6})~', $filtered, $matchesAs);
```

The $filtered variable content is:

```
103031Theory and blahblah from blahblahblah421001279Martin Pascal, Michael TruthLSS
```

And I want to get the first appeareance of "103031" or any six-number group at the very start of the line. The regex expression is working properly at online testers, but when I try it with "preg_match" `$matchesAs` is empty. `(\d{6})` works well without `^`...

Comment: The 6 digit number is not at the beginning of the string then. Try `'~^\W*(\d{6})~'`

Comment: the 6 digit number is always at the very beginning of the string.

Comment: By at the start of the line do you mean at the start of the string or start of a new line? because ^ only matches the start of the string unless you are in multiline mode.

Comment: Some information must be missing, [because...](https://3v4l.org/FY2IQ)

Comment: See [the demo](https://ideone.com/Lxvb5w) - your regex matches the number

Comment: are you sure you are not overwriting the $matchesAs variable? OR maybe the `preg_match` is in some conditions in which its not getting in.

Comment: Yes it is working at my end correctly as you have shown in the demo. :) this is the correct regex pattern

Comment: try "^/(\d{6})/m" as search string. Like @Someone said, "^" means start of line. "/m" says RegEx to use multiline mode. A normal String is not a line for RegEx as long you don't say him that it is Multiline.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. It's strange, maybe I can't see something. If I change ^(\d{6}) for (\d{6}) works well. But when I put "^" then $matchesAs is empty. Maybe the $filtered variable is not clean at his beginning.

Comment: Or with regexp, `intval($yourStringStartingWithDigits, 10)` (since you know the number is always at the start of the string)

Comment: "Maybe the $filtered variable is not clean at his beginning. " - well, take a look: `foreach(str_split($filtered, 1) as $c) { printf('%02X ', ord($c)); }` if `1` is the first (ascii/...) character then the output will start with `31`.

Comment: The output it's not 31 :O but I can't detect any blank space or unwanted symbol with an "echo", "var_dump" or "print_r".